# J2ME video capture throws MediaException: Invalid locator: capture://video

Tags: java-me, lwuit, mmapi

I was trying to capture a video in a J2ME application with the following snippet

```
private void createCamera() throws IOException, MediaException {
    videoComponent = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer("capture://video");
    videoComponent.setPreferredH(height);
    videoComponent.setPreferredW(cameraForm.getWidth());
    player = (Player) videoComponent.getNativePeer();
    player.realize();
    player.prefetch();
    videoControl = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");
}
```

When I run the application on a real device, I get the error:

```
javax.microedition.media.MediaException: Invalid locator: capture://video
```

If I use the string capture://image it will only show the camera for images only. How do I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are to try get by [device name](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#media-locator), like devcam0/devcam1? Do you use nokia phone?

Comment: I didn't find nokia with cable at home. Maybe you could use this:     `player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");`